# Spring Cloud Gateway - Per-route security configuration. Dynamic reload on client registration

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using SCG with Eureka, with discovery client based routes. Some clients have different security requirements (some unauthenticated, some with certain roles). I can set a path matcher on the `ServerHttpSecurity` object that builds the `SecurityWebFilterChain`, but I don't know in advance if any of the discovered services will be one of those that requires a different configuration from the default. I'm considering using metadata from the discovery client to configure this.

Is there something in Spring Security to refresh the `ServerHttpSecurity` config based on some application event or something like that? Or is there something SCG that controls this? Or am I overthinking this and it just happens at some point?